# How to split a string if any chracter is found in java

Tags: java, regex, string, split, tokenize

Given:

```
String one = "show ip interface brief | include 1234**\n Gi1/23.1234  xxx.225.xxx.106 YES manual up  up";
```

I want to split

```
Gi1/23.1234  xxx.225.xxx.106 YES manual up up
```

into different tokens and remove

```
show ip interface brief | include  1234**
```

Output should be:

```
String[] tokens = ["Gi1/23.1234", "xxx.225.xxx.106", "Yes", "manual", "up", "up"]
```

Comment: well... you said it. use the split() method of the String class

Comment: Your post is almost unreadable. Anyway have you tried anything, like `split` method from String class? Can we see your attempts?

Comment: Ya i have tried but I not able to split second line starting from Gil.. Because split method do not split"|" . Please if u can do any help its really urgent

Comment: You have to escape the `regex` character `"|"`. Example: `string.split("\\|")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `String`'s methods [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) together here.

```
String one = "show ip interface brief | include 1234**\n Gi1/23.1234  xxx.225.xxx.106 YES manual up  up";
String[] tokens = one.replaceAll("[^\\n]+\\n\\s*", "").split("\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
```

Output

```
[Gi1/23.1234, xxx.225.xxx.106, YES, manual, up, up]
```